# Formatting numeric values to time in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time, lubridate, chron

I want to format my numeric sleep minutes in a data frame to time in R. For example, this is what the data frame looks like:

```
TotalMinutesAsleep 327

sleep.day.1$TotalMinutesAsleep <- hms(sleep.day.1$TotalMinutesAsleep)
```

I need a quick and easy solution.

Thx,

Comment: Thanks again, I done that and created a new data frame. Now, I am struggling with plotting this data. Mine is all over the place and most tutorials go over dates and not hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If these values are in minutes, convert to seconds and use `seconds_to_period`

```
library(lubridate)
period1 <- seconds_to_period(sleep.day.1$TotalMinutesAsleep * 60)
```

then, we may format it with

```
sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', period1@hour, period1@minute, second(period1))
```

Comment: Ahhh, library(hms), I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: sprintf? I will use it, do you have a link to explain?

Comment: @Baccara the `seconds_to_period` returns a `period` class object and `sprintf` is just doing the formatting on the extracted period elements with `@`

Comment: I have created a new data frame with everything formatted. I am struggling with graphing it. Is there a package that will help?

Comment: @Baccara you may post as a new question.  If the current solution works, please consider to accept solution

Answer (score 1):

We coul use `hms` part of the `tidyverse`: A simple class for storing time-of-day values

```
library(hms)
hms(sleep.day.1$TotalMinutesAsleep*60)
```

output:

```
05:27:00
```